# How long does it take to decrypt a hard drive with FileVault?

Tags: hard-drive, catalina, encryption, filevault

I'm decrypting my hard drive with `sudo fdesetup disable` (because system Preferences would stop responding when I clicked "Decrypt"), and it doesn't show the progress.

So I left my iMac on sleep mode overnight, and it's still not done. Is it even doing anything or does it just take a while to decrypt a 1TB hard drive?

Also, is there a way to see how long it takes until it's done?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't do it while it's asleep, but idk of any way to show progress.

Comment: @klanomath How do you get to see how long it takes until it's done? It doesn't say in SysPrefs, and entering `fdesetup status -extended` in a new window just says `Volume is APFS. (FileVault Enabled)`.

Comment: @klanomath The thing is when i enter `fdesetup status -extended` it just says `FileVault is On. Volume is APFS. (FileVault Enabled)` and nothing else, not even a percentage.

Comment: @OMN30 Have you started decryption already?

Comment: @klanomath Yes, it has been decrypting for 24 hours.

Comment: @klanomath They both say: `FileVault: Yes (Unlocked)`

Comment: @klanomath Should I then force quit teminal and try again?

Comment: @OMN30 I would terminate whatever is running in Terminal (ctrl-c). Then `diskutil verifyDisk disk0` & `diskutil verifyVolume disk1` (assuming disk0 is your internal disk and disk1 is the APFS container scheme containing the volumes to decrypt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It depends.**

There's several factors that go into decrypting a drive:

- The CPU - how quickly it can "crunch" the numbers to encrypt/decrypt
- Whether or not your have a [T2 chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple-designed_processors#Apple_T2)
- Drive size - bigger means more things to process
- Type of drive - SSDs are fairly quick whereas mechanical drives are much, much slower.
- How it's connected - USB 2.0 (480Mb/s) versus USB 3.0 (5Gb/s) versus SATA II (3Gb/s) versus SATA III (6Gb/s).  All these different speeds factor in how quickly the decryption process goes.

When I had to do DoD wipes of mechanical drives, many of them were only 250GB, it could take up to 48 hours and it was just a "3 pass of writing zeros".

> So I left my iMac on sleep mode overnight,

When you put your Mac to sleep, it stops the processes.  Don't put it to sleep while decrypting.